# InputProcessor NullPointerException

Tags: libgdx

I'm working on game, using LibGDX and have some problems with Input Processor. Wnen I launch my game and press Right button it crashes with `NullPointerException`

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Input.Keys.RIGHT && player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <=0.5) {
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.1f, 0), player.b2body.getWorldCenter(),true);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}



public  void update (float dt) {


        world.step(1/10f,6,2);
        player.update(dt);
       // handleInput(dt);

        MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
        if(player.b2body.getPosition().x>=SonicZP.V_WIDTH/2/SonicZP.PPM)
        gamecam.position.x = player.b2body.getPosition().x;

        if(player.b2body.getPosition().y>=SonicZP.V_HEIGHT/2/SonicZP.PPM)
            gamecam.position.y = player.b2body.getPosition().y;
        gamecam.update();



            renderer.setView(gamecam);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace

Answer (score 2):

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

Should be placed in your show()-method in your Game class that extends Screen.

Comment: The keyDown() method above the render() implies that he is implementing InputProcessor. He should therefore not instantiate a new InputProcessor, but use the class itself as InputProcessor

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your class extends Screen and implements InputProcessor.

You should remove

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

from you render(). Btw, this should NEVER be in render().
Instead in your show() set:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
```

since the class you are in implements InputProcessor and IS your InputProcessor.